# How to adress the row with minimum value of the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

this is the code used for creating the df:

```
team = np.array(['Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari', 'Ferrari'])
year = np.array([2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020])
roundn = np.array([4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
points = np.array([6, 10, 14, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])

df = pd.DataFrame(team, columns=["team"])
df['year'] = year
df['roundn'] = roundn
df['points'] = points

df = df.groupby(["team", 'year']).apply(display)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nxfl.png)

So for every group I would like to add the new column that for the minimum value of the roundn column is 1 and else is 0.

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(np.argmin(df['roundn']), 1, 0)
```

Do you have any ideas how to make it work?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df.groupby(["team", 'year']).apply(display)` returns `None` so you are setting `df = None`

Comment: in jupyter it works correctly

Comment: It's displaying the data, but not returning any data. You can check what `df` is after that line.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I need to find the solution to adress the minimum value of every group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces a single new `DataFrame`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['team', 'year'])['roundn'].idxmin(), 'new_col'] = 1
df['new_col'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you can also add a new column per group and combine later with `pd.concat`

```
groups = []
for n, g in df.groupby(['team', 'year']):
    g['new_col'] = np.where(g.roundn.min()==g.roundn, 1, 0)
    groups.append(g)

pd.concat(groups)
```